# Populate templates using list,detail generic views

Tags: python, django, view, generics

I am creating a list of users present in my database, they are being displayed in user_list.html template through the use of generic views, but my models inherit many of its properties from other classes in the model. Now I want that when a user clicks on his name he should be redirected to the user_detail.html page and he should get his details here.
The details are to be picked up from the database, it is just picking the values from the same model for which the queryset is defined.

my views.py looks like

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
   from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
   from django.views.generic.list_detail import object_list, object_detail

   from contacts.models import *

   def employee_list(request, queryset=None, **kwargs):
       if queryset is None:
          queryset = Employee.objects.all()
      return object_list(
          request,
          queryset=queryset,
          paginate_by=20,
          **kwargs)

  def employee_detail(request, employee_id):
      return object_detail(
          request,
          queryset= Employee.objects.all(),
         # extra_context ={"EC_list": EmergencyContact.objects.all()},
          object_id=employee_id)
```

urls.py

```
from contacts.views import employees

   urlpatterns = patterns('',
       url(r'^$',
           employees.employee_list,
           name='contacts_employee_list'),
       url(r'^(?P<employee_id>\d+)/$',
           employees.employee_detail,
          name='contacts_employee_detail'),
```

my employee_deatil.html looks like

```
 {% block title %} Employee details {% endblock %}
   {% block heading1%}<h1> Employee's Details </h1>{% endblock %}
   {% block right_menu %}
      {% if object %}
         <ul>
           <li> Name:{{ object.full_name }}</li>
           <li> Contact No.: {{ object.phone_number }}</li>
         <!--  <li> Refrence Contact No.: {{ EC_list.contact }}</li> -->
          <li> Blood Group: {{ object.blood_type }}</li>
          <li> Martial Status: {{ object.martial_status }}</li>
          <li> Nationality: {{ object.about }}</li>
          <!-- <li> Relationship: {{ EC_list.relationship }}</li>
           <li>Course: {{ object.course }}</li>  -->
        </ul>
        {% else %}
            No Registered user present.
        {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
```

So please help me to figure out that how can I display all the data of employee which is present in the other models. Thank you!

Comment: Not at all a good idea to include line numbers in code. You should remove them.

Comment: What is your problem? What's currently not working? What are you expecting to see, and what are you seeing instead?

Comment: Hello buddy I wanted to populate my template by all the details available in the database models. My models have relationships as well Foreignkey etc and I m not able to show those attributes of my models which have a foreign key relation with some other model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you want to display information about the employee which is stored in other models.

I assume you know that you can pre-filter in the view and send an extra context variable with a queryset. using your existing line `extra_context ="EC_list": EmergencyContact.objects.all()` selects too many. I assume your EmergencyContact model has a foreign key to Employee
 ( `employee = ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='emergency_contacts')` ). In this case you must pass your extra context filtered.

```
def employee_detail(request, employee_id):
    return object_detail(
        request,
        queryset= Employee.objects.all(),
        extra_context ={"EC_list": EmergencyContact.objects.filter(employee__pk=employee_id)},
        object_id=employee_id)
```

this will filter the list to just the emergency contacts you need.

```
{% block title %} Employee details {% endblock %}
{% block heading1%}<h1> Employee's Details </h1>{% endblock %}
{% block right_menu %}
   {% if object %}
      <ul>
        <li> Name:{{ object.full_name }}</li>
        <li> Contact No.: {{ object.phone_number }}</li>
        <li> Blood Group: {{ object.blood_type }}</li>
        <li> Martial Status: {{ object.martial_status }}</li>
        <li> Nationality: {{ object.about }}</li>
        <li> Course: {{ object.course }}</li>
        <li> Emergency Contacts: 
          <ul> 
            {% for EC in EC_list %} 
            <li> Name: {{ EC.name }} </li>
            <li> Contact No.: {{ EC.contact }}</li>
            <li> Relationship: {{ EC.relationship }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
     {% else %}
         No Registered user present.
     {% endif %}
 {% endblock %}
```

Of course, this is only one way to do it. if you don't need any fancy filters on emergency contacts, you can use foreign key reverse lookups within the template. i.e. get rid of the extra_context for EC_list and replace the contact rendering function with this:

```
        <li> Emergency Contacts: 
          <ul> 
            {% for EC in object.emergency_contacts %} 
            <li> Name: {{ EC.name }} </li>
            <li> Contact No.: {{ EC.contact }}</li>
            <li> Relationship: {{ EC.relationship }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </li>
```

Remember that we have `employee = ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='emergency_contacts')` as a foreign key from EmergencyContact to Employee. not only does this declaration add the employee field to EmergencyContact but it adds an extra *virtual* field to Employee with the name 'emergency_contacts'. this virtual field returns a queryset of all Emergency Contacts linked to the current employee.

Let me know if you have any questions or need links to documentation

EDIT: for readability sake, considder setting the template_object_name parameter of the generic view.

```
def employee_detail(request, employee_id):
    return object_detail(request, queryset= Employee.objects.all(),
                  object_id=employee_id, template_object_name='employee')

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        <li> Name: {{ employee.full_name }}</li>
        <li> Emergency Contacts: 
          <ul> 
            {% for EC in employee.emergency_contacts %} 
            <li> Name: {{ EC.name }} </li>
            <li> Contact No.: {{ EC.contact }}</li>
            <li> Relationship: {{ EC.relationship }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful answer it really works,,,,,, and if u could send me some related links for this article than I will be very thankful to you.........

Comment: Hello dear,now i wanted to display the attributes which are themselves a foreign key of other classes so how to call them in my template.example: I have EmergencyContact which has one attribute contact=models.ForeignKey(Person,verbose_name=_('contact'),related_name='emergency_contact_to') but this class Person also has its attribute phone_number pointing to some other class i.e. phone_number=generic.GenericRelation('PhoneNumber'). I m not able to access phone no. so how can i show it in the template.

Comment: can you post the related model definitions?